# Update a chart from the event of another

Tags: javascript, anychart

[image]

Is it possible with AnyChart, to update the line chart depending on the click made on the sunburst chart ?
[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/wizicer/f662a0b04425fc0f7489) is an example of what I'd would like to achieve with anyChart, but made here with d3.js (sunburst take time to load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You should create a chart listener on mouse over and inside the event handler update the second chart. In the comment below you can find a sample which describes how to achieve that. Try to hover with a cursor 'HR' and 'Sales' points, you will how the second chart updates its data.

Comment: Many thanks. It work. Up voted and marked as answered